# Writing CSS for different brands

Tags: css

This is a somewhat abstract question but here goes.

A company recently partnered with another company for a small project but their brands are not aligned, so in certain areas of their site the pages need to respect the brand guidelines of whatever company they represent.

Currently all of the CSS is geared towards a singular brand e.g.

```
.solution-featured-video__title {
    font-family: CircularStd;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.33;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This is a piece of styling for the title of a solution video.

If the other brand wanted an identical component and I stick loosely to BEM, would it be appropriate to just use modifiers?

E.g.

```
.solution-featured-video__title--other-brand
```

In light of the comments I ask because there is also a business rule: whenever someone types easy in any form i.e. Easy, easy, EASY, it needs to be changed to easy.

My idea was to programmatically wrap a span around each instance.

Comment: Please tell your problem more in programming way

Comment: Yes it would be appropriate in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under BEM (Block, Element, Modifier), I think it would be perfectly acceptable to use the modifier as a means of adding brand specific styling to the element.

```
.solution-featured-video__title {
    font-family: CircularStd;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.33;
    color: #fff;

    &--brand1 {
        color: #000
    }

}
```

You are effectively just modifying the styling of the block based on brand